# Anyone else seeing odd UIImage behaviors on iOS 14 specifically in production/TestFlight?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, ios14

Anyone else seeing odd UIImage behaviors on iOS 14 specifically in production/TestFlight?

When built from XCode (Version 12.0.1) to an iOS 14 device, assets, icons, images are all rendered normally. When uploaded to Testflight though, all of the images in our app are not showing up at all. The same Testflight app on an iOS 13 device shows all images perfectly fine, so it seems specific to iOS 14.

Pretty much any UIImage set programmatically in a UIImageView; local assets (icons), images downloaded, etc, are not showing. They're being set simply through UIImageView.image = UIImage. Even when using something like UIImagePicker, the image preview taken from the camera shows up blank.
(Interestingly, the same local icons that are set through Interface Builder show up fine)

Finding this very difficult to debug, because it's not reproducible through local XCode builds, even on iOS 14 devices. The behavior only shows up in Testflight/production.

Comment: Try updating to a more recent version of Xcode (eg 12.5) and see if the problem persists.